# what does scope.$parent represent in the following directive, if scope is isolated?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

i am new to angular directives. i am little bit confused in the following directive :

```
app.directive('person', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      header: '='
    },
    transclude:true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
      scope.person = {
        name: 'Directive Joe',
        profession: 'Scope guy'
      };

      scope.header = 'Directive\'s header';
      transclude(scope.$parent, function(clone, scope) {
        element.append(clone);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Html :

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <person header="header">
    <h2>{{header}}</h2>
    <p>Hello, I am {{person.name}} and,</p>
    <p>I am a {{person.profession}}</p>
  </person>
</body>
```

in this directive `scope` is used as isolated. then what does `scope.$parent` represent in `transclude` function .according to me if `scope` is isolated then `scope.$parent` represent `$rootScope`. is it ? please explain it in details. Thanks !

Comment: [$rootScope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope) Every scope in angular inherits it

Answer (score 0):

Your scope.$parent represents the parent scope. What the parent scope is depends on where you placed your directive.

For example, if you have the following:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <person header="Hello World!"></person>
</div>
```

Then, you parent scope would be the scope in MyController. If you do not have ng-controller declared in the above situation, then scope.$parent would represent the $rootScope.

Comment: But here Scope is isolated.means Scope doesn't inherit any scope. am i wrong ?

Comment: Isolate scope is to isolate the scope yes, but there is still a way to access the parent scope in an isolated scope. That's by calling $scope.$parent, but the $scope itself is still isolated from any inheritence.